# Talend FileInputRaw get htmlcode

Tags: talend

I have a folder with html files and I want to get the html code using FileInputRaw. 
The components are working fine without any errors. However, the first file is always null (no html code ). Can someone tell me why?

Thanks a lot!

Job Flow:

[image]

Execution Output:

[image]

Comment: Is it always the first file in the list? Have you tried to remove that file and run with the remaining seven files? Just a wild guess: Could it be that Talend chokes on the spaces in the filename? Have you tried to remove the spaces?

Comment: yes, have tried everything you mentioned...removed that file, removed the spaces..and still it only occurs for the first file

Answer (score 0):

You should use a tJavaRow (or tJavaFlex) and not a tJava.

tJava will be executed before the row data are passed, so it will be empty for the first run.
So, as a rule of thumb, NEVER use a "plain" tJava connected to a data flow row.
Use it only on triggers (onOk, onError, if)